# In PHP i have used the logic to find the digits in a number, but i get a default output which is "325" instead of "4" for four digit number

Tags: php

**Here is the Code below, please review and provide me a solution. It will be very helpful**

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<?php
$x=0;   
$num=1000;
do{
    $x++;
    $num/=10;

}while($num!=0);
echo "$x";

?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying `$num` inside the loop to see what values it has?

Comment: Yes, I have. indeed it displays the $num inside the loop, it displays the quotient number after the division operation is completed each time the loop runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while condition is incorrect, you will never reach 0, well not until your float can't be evaluated accurately anymore. Since you are dividing a number (`$num`) by 10 and setting the result to `$num` on every iteration `$num` becoming closer and closer to zero. When you divide a non-zero number in this way the number gets closer and closer to zero, but will never actually reach 0 ([You have discovered a limit to infinity](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/limits-infinity.html)). The reason your code does not cause an infinite loop and crash, is because PHP (and all languages) are limited to how small (or large) of a number a single variable can represent. Have a look at [this PHP doc on floating point numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) for some more insight on float values and their possible accuracy. Once your `$num` value becomes small enough, PHP can no longer represent the value accurately leading to `0`. Which as you discovered takes `325` iterations when starting at `1000`.

You should instead check for when your `$num` becomes less then `1`.

Example:

```
<?php
$x = 0;   
$num = 1000;
do {
    $x++;
    $num /= 10;
} while($num >= 1);

echo $x;
```

[Live Example](https://3v4l.org/XIqhP)

#### Using Original Condition

You could use your original while condition `$num != 0` if you modify your calculation to round `$num` down to the nearest whole number. For example:

```
<?php
$x = 0;   
$num = 1000;
do {
    $x++;
    $num = floor($num / 10);
} while($num != 0);

echo $x;
```

[Live Example](https://3v4l.org/XbQLQ)

Comment: This did help me, a real solution indeed. Thank you very much, brother, I am still confused because the loop is supposed to stop when the $num becomes 0. logically it was correct, but can you enlighten me, next time if I do such examples, would you recommend me using $num!=0? or other condition examples?

Comment: @CuChakma I updated my answer with a more detailed explanation as to why this happens and what I meant by "you will never reach 0". As far as your condition goes, that all depends on what it is you are trying to do with your code. Different scenarios will require different logic. In this scenario, there aren't a lot of other ways to control the logic, you could use your original `$num != 0` if you instead round the answer down on each iteration.  Also included an example showing that.

Comment: brother I understood now clearly. The reason I was not able to get the appropriate result is that I used it because clearly the division result was arriving at 0.19 or 0.17 not exactly 0.0000000000. so theoretically it was still divisible until it becomes 0.000000000 :). so you used the floor function to round up the $num result